# How to Flip An Image in C#

Tags: c#

I want to flip this image,
[image]

So that it appears like this,
[image]

However the code I have written makes it appear like this,
[image]

What am I doing wrong in my code?

```
    int Height = TransformedPic.GetLength(0);
        int Width = TransformedPic.GetLength(1);

        for (int i = 0; i < Height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Width / 2; j++)
            {
                TransformedPic[i, j] = TransformedPic[i, ((Width) - (j + 1))];
            }
        }
```

Comment: Create an image that has only, say, eight by eight pixels, initialize each pixel to a different value, and **debug your program with that test case**. On every step in the debugger, predict what *will* happen vs what *should* happen, and you will find your bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You overwrite data and they get lost
2. You flip wrong direction

This should work:

```
        int Height = TransformedPic.GetLength(0);
        int Width = TransformedPic.GetLength(1);

        for (int i = 0; i < Height / 2; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Width; j++)
            {
                var tmp = TransformedPic[i, j];
                TransformedPic[i, j] = TransformedPic[Height - 1 - i, j];
                TransformedPic[Height - 1 - i, j] = tmp;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

It is probable that by the time your code gets into half of your image, the second half is already updated with the first.

Try this instead:

```
    var newPic = TransformedPic.Clone(); // Clone your pic to a new object. 
    int Height = TransformedPic.GetLength(0);
    int Width = TransformedPic.GetLength(1);

    for (int i = 0; i < Height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < Width / 2; j++)
        {
            newPic[i, j] = TransformedPic[i, ((Width) - (j + 1))];
        }
    }
    TransformedPic = newPic;
```

Comment: Not sure what time `TransformedPic` is, but typically indexers are `width, height`. Judging by OPs current output, it seems this is the case. This code will flip it horizontally, not vertically, and will break (or at least be incorrect) if `Width != Height`. It should be: `newPic[j, i] = TransformedPic[j, Height - i - 1];` and the loop for `j` should be to `Width`, not `Width / 2`

Comment: @Rob why are using Transformed [j,i] instead of TransformedPic [i,j]? And the TransformedPic is a copy of the orignal image that is loaded into my program, I only want to alter TransformedPic as I have other processes within my program as well which make use of it.

Comment: @CoolCat Because the indexer usually asks for `[x,y]`, where `x` is the horizontal position, and `y` is vertical. However, `i` is your vertical position (as you're looping up to height), so it shouldn't be stored in `x`. Could you tell me what type `TransformedPic` is?

Comment: @Frank Fajardo I get the error, "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of _FileName_ type 'object' when I write newPic[i,j] within the loop. How do I fix this?

Comment: @Rob TransformedPic is a copy of an array Original, which is the original copy of the image I loaded into my program. Its just the name of the array my bitmap image (as shown above) is saved under. Sorry if my explanation is bad, I'm new to coding.

Answer (score 1):

If `start` and `end` are the inclusive edges of a range, then the typical (and easy memorable) flip (or reverse) algorithm is a follows

```
for (int lo = start, hi = end; lo < hi; lo++, hi--)
    swapelements(lo, hi);
```

Applying it to your case:

First, a small helper method

```
static void Swap<T>(ref T x, ref T y)
{
    var temp = x; x = y; y = temp;
}
```

Then, starting with

```
int height = TransformedPic.GetLength(0);
int width = TransformedPic.GetLength(1);
```

To flip horizontally

```
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    for (int lo = 0, hi = width - 1; lo < hi; lo++, hi--)
        Swap(ref TransformedPic[i, lo], ref TransformedPic[i, hi]);
```

To flip vertically (as in the question)

```
for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    for (int lo = 0, hi = height - 1; lo < hi; lo++, hi--)
        Swap(ref TransformedPic[lo, i], ref TransformedPic[hi, i]);
```

Finally, it's worth mentioning that you can use [Image.RotateFlip Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.rotateflip%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to achieve the same, without a need to take the image pixels into array buffer and do your own processing.